# Passing parameters from c# to powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell

I created a powershell script that consists of:

```
param($ServerName, $Location)

"Application Name: $ServerName"
"Location: $Location"
```

when I am in the powershell and I run `.\Params.ps1 ConsoleApp1 Washington, D.C.` it will display:

```
Application Name: ConsoleApp1
Location: Washington D.C.
```

So I know this works just fine. Now I am wanting to take this to c# and perform parameter passing.

In my console application, I created the following:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] scriptParam = { "ConsoleApp1", "Washington, D.C."};
        string powerShell = PerformScript(scriptParam);
        Console.WriteLine(powerShell);
        Console.WriteLine("\nPowershell script excuted!!");          
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string PerformScript(string scriptParameters)
    {
        InitialSessionState runspaceConfiguration = InitialSessionState.Create();
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);

        runspace.Open();

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
       

        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.Runspace = runspace;
        ps.AddCommand(@"C:\Users\users\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\powershell\Params.ps1");

        foreach (string scriptParameter in scriptParameters)
        {
            ps.AddParameter(scriptParameter);
        }

        Collection<PSObject> psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();
        runspace.Close();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new();

        foreach (PSObject item in psObjects)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(item.ToString());
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

but when I run the program I get an `Exception Unhandled` on the line

`Collection<PSObject> psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();`

> System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: 'The pipeline does not contain a command.'

*Am I doing something incorrect when passing the parameters?*

---

Updated code:

```
    static string PerformScript(string[] scriptParameters)
    {
        InitialSessionState runspaceConfiguration = InitialSessionState.Create();
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);

        runspace.Open();

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

        using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            var result = ps.AddCommand(@"C:\Users\users\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\powershell\Params.ps1")
              .AddArgument("ConsoleApp1")
              .AddArgument("Washington, D.C.")
              .Invoke();
            foreach (var o in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o);
            }
        }

        Collection<PSObject> psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();
        runspace.Close();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new();

        foreach (PSObject item in psObjects)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(item.ToString());
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I don't C# much except for when I need to P/Invoke so I'm not sure this is accurate but it would appear that you're trying to loop over a string, rather than a  string array:  string[].  Look at how Performscript() is declaring it's param (scriptParameters) and also what you're passing to it.... both strings.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed that issue. However, when I ran the program it returned a new error. **System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException:** 'The pipeline does not contain a command.' @thepip3r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.AddArgument()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddArgument), not [`.AddParameter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddParameter).

What you're trying to pass are *positional* (unnamed) arguments, i.e. mere parameter *values* whose target parameter is *implied by their position*, which is what `.AddArgument()` is for.

By contrast, `.AddParameter()` is for *named* arguments, where you specify the  parameter *name* first, followed by its *value* (argument).

Here's a simplified example:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
  var result = ps.AddCommand(@"C:\Users\users\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\powershell\Params.ps1")
    .AddArgument("ConsoleApp1")
    .AddArgument("Washington, D.C.")
    .Invoke();
  foreach (var o in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(o);
  }
}
```

Note: The above uses the much simplified API that is available directly via the methods of a [`PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell) instance (created with `.Create()`): If *automatically* creating a runspace with a default session state is sufficient, there is *no* need for *explicit* creation of a runspace with `RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()`, a session state with `InitialSessionState.Create()`, and a runspace's pipeline with `.CreatePipeline()` - see the bottom section for how to apply the techniques to your code.

---

As for **what you tried**:

If you mistakenly use `.AddParameter()` with a single method argument only, what the PowerShell SDK does is to default the omitted parameter *value* to `true`, so that `.AddParameter('foo')` is the equivalent of passing `-foo: $true` from inside PowerShell.

This works as intended only if you're passing the *name* of a parameter that is a *switch* parameter (of type [`System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter), `[switch]` in PowerShell code).

---

**Applied to your code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
      PerformScript(
        @"C:\Users\users\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\powershell\Params.ps1", 
        new string[] { "ConsoleApp1", "Washington, D.C." }
      )
    );
}

static string PerformScript(string scriptPath, string[] scriptArguments)
{
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new();
  using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
  {
    ps.AddCommand(scriptPath);
    foreach (var arg in scriptArguments)
    {
      ps.AddArgument(arg);
    }
    foreach (var o in ps.Invoke())
    {
      stringBuilder.AppendLine(o.ToString());
    }
  }
  return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```